# Spring annotation based validation is not working

Tags: spring, rest, validation

I am using Spring 4.x for my application. There i have some rest api exposed and i want to validate the request body json using annotations. But the validations are not getting triggered. Code Snippets of my service:

1. I am using @Validated Annotation from springframework validation package at class level of service.

```
@Validated
@Api(value="Sample Rest service")
@Path("/test")
public class testService{
.....
}
```

2. In the request method, i am using @Valid annotation on request body:

```
@POST
@Path("/sample")
public Response createResource(@Valid @RequestBody Resource res){
.....
}
```

3. In the POJO class of Resource, i have just added @NotNull annotation for a field which has public setters and getters.

```
public class Resource{
@NotNull(message="Name can't be null")
private String name;
.....
}
```

But it is not triggering any validation error.I am not using spring boot or jpa framework in my application.
Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: Which `@Valid` annotation are you using, 2, you are combining Spring MVC and Jax-WS (which is probably the root-cause) 3. make sure you have a validator implementation on your classpath (like hibernate-validator 5 or 6, don't use 7 as that is a JakartaEE implementation).

Comment: 1. @Valid annotation is from javax.validation.
2. Actually this is how the implementation is there currently for rest apis. Please suggest what change need to be done.
3. Hibernate is not there in my application